# Is there an optimised yet safe way to transfer bulk data from DropBox to OneDrive?

Tags: cloud-storage, dropbox, microsoft-onedrive

The brute force way to do this is to download all data from DropBox to a local PC and then re-upload to OneDrive, but I see there are "cloud based" solutions (i.e. 
[cloudfuze](https://www.cloudfuze.com/transfer-files-dropbox-onedrive-onedrive-business-office-365/), [uBackup](https://cloud.ubackup.com/articles/migrate-dropbox-to-onedrive-6688.html)), which I assume do this via faster back-end links. Are any of these services certified as safe? It seems extremely risky to me to trust a third-party to transfer all of my data, but it would be a much faster mechanism to transfer c20GB of data.

Answer (score 1):

> Are any of these services certified as safe?

The short answer is "No". The longer one is equally discouraging. Who would certify the services, and by what standards?

> ... which I assume do this via faster back-end links.

Did you find this written down anywhere? I highly doubt it, they'll just offer to move the data for you.

> It seems extremely risky to me to trust a third-party to transfer all of my data...

You are absolutely right. Please don't use third party services to move your data, especially since they will certainly require authorisation to read your files from one services and to write them into another.

> but it would be a much faster mechanism to transfer c20GB of data

You can't be sure of this, you'd need to measure.

Just sync your local DropBox then re-upload manually to OneDrive from a trusted workstation, if this is what you need doing.

Comment: OK, thank you. I think I needed someone to tell me what I already knew was the best approach! :)

Comment: Note that the trusted workstation doesn't have to be a local machine on your network. You could setup an appropriately secured and isolated VM on the cloud and use that. The benefit being that bandwidth to and from a cloud VM is often massively greater than a home internet connection. Just watch out for traffic volume costs, if applicable.